# Getting top 10 Values in a JSON File

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, parsing

This is an example of my JSON file.

```
[
    {"Variable":"Hello","Variable1":20}, {"Variable":"Hi","Variable1":30},
    {"Variable":"How","Variable1":40}, {"Variable":"Who","Variable1":50},
    {"Variable":"Where","Variable1":60}, {"Variable":"This","Variable1":100},
    {"Variable":"Pork","Variable1":10}, {"Variable":"Creep","Variable1":90},
    {"Variable":"Mega Creeps","Variable1":80}, {"Variable":"LOL","Variable1":0},
    {"Variable":"ROFL","Variable1":0}, {"Variable":"LMAO","Variable1":0},
    {"Variable":"POP","Variable1":0}, {"Variable":"LOVE","Variable1":0},
    {"Variable":"PICK","Variable1":0}, {"Variable":"WHIZ","Variable1":0},
    {"Variable":"BORED","Variable1":0}, {"Variable":"KILLAH","Variable1":0},
    {"Variable":"LOLLING","Variable1":0}, {"Variable":"HALOO  HALOO","Variable1":0}
]
```

How can I get only the Top 10 from highest Variable1 number to the least? But gonna be passing the JSON file as the same format.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First, parse the JSON into an array of Objects:

```
var data = JSON.parse(json);
```

Then combine `sort` and `slice` to achieve your goal:

```
var top10 = data.sort(function(a, b) { return a.Variable1 < b.Variable1 ? 1 : -1; })
                .slice(0, 10);
```

See [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: There's a typo in the comparison. Should be ``a.Variable1 > b.Variable1``

Comment: No, having `a.Variable1 > b.Variable1` will show you the generate an array and show lowest values. Old post, but may be helpful for someone who wants to save a minute.

Comment: @LongZheng [No](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with [Alasql](http://github.com/agershun/alasql) JavaScript library. It download json file, parse it, and run 
SQL statement on it. This is a sample how to take top 10 directly from JSON file:

```
<script src="alasql.min.js></script>
<script>
    alasql("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM JSON('mydata.json') ORDER BY Variable1 DESC",[], function(top10){
        console.log(top10);
    });
</script>
```

Or if you already have data in memory:

```
    var data = [{"Variable":"Hello","Variable1":20},{"Variable":"Hi","Variable1":30}];
    var res = alasql("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ? ORDER BY Variable1 DESC",[data]);
```

Try [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/xa3evfg8/) in jsFiddle.

Comment: is there any way to achieve this using php ??

Comment: nice library thanks for sharing